# Getting the number of old issues and the table (login and number of commits) of the most active members of the repository

Tags: python-3.x, github-api

I can not get the above information using github.api. Reading the documentation did not help much. There is still no complete understanding of the work with dates. Here is an example of my code for getting open issues:

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime


username = '\'
password = '\'

another_page = True
opened = 0
closed = 0
api_oldest = 'https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues? 
per_page=5&q=sort=created:>`date -v-14d "+%Y-%m-%d"`&order=asc'
api_issue = 'https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues? 
page=1&per_page=5000'
api_pulls = 'https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/pulls?page=1'

datetime.now()
while another_page:
    r = requests.get(api_issue, auth=(username, password))
    #json_response = json.loads(r.text)
    #results.append(json_response)
    if 'next' in r.links:
        api_issue = r.links['next']['url']
        if item['state'] == 'open':
             opened += 1
        else:
             closed += 1 
    else:
        another_page=False
datetime.now()

print(opened)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. For example, what does `item` represent ?. Your code can be modified as follows to iterate and get the number of open issues .

```
import requests

username = '/'
password = '/'

another_page = True
opened = 0
closed = 0

api_issue = "https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues?page=1&per_page=5000"


while another_page:
    r = requests.get(api_issue, auth=(username, password))
    json_response = r.json()
    #results.append(json_response)
    for item in json_response:
        if item['state'] == 'open':
             opened += 1
        else:
             closed += 1 

    if 'next' in r.links:
        api_issue = r.links['next']['url']
    else:
        another_page=False

print(opened)
```

If you want issues that were created in the last 14 days, you could make the api request using the following URL.

```
api_oldest = "https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues?q=sort=created:>`date -d '14 days ago'`&order=asc"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really helpful. But what about getting old issues? I would like to know how to get this information using curl to get started.

Comment: Oh.. the curl for the issues created in the last 14 days is as follows: `curl "https://api.github.com/repos/grpc/grpc/issues?q=sort=created:>`date -d '14 days ago'`&order=asc"` .